# STOMP Websocket connection via Spring Cloud Gateway suddenly closes after sending first message

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring Cloud Gateway in Microservice system with Eureka as service discovery and a business service using STOMP websocket with SockJS implemented.
When I connect the STOMP client (which uses ReactJS) directly with the business service, everything works fine. However, if I do connect via Spring Cloud Gateway, the websocket connection closes immediately after sending first message, but after I refresh the page everything works fine.
This is my gateway route configuration:

```
     - id: chat-service
      uri: lb://chat-service
      predicates:
        - Path=/chat/**
      filters:
        - name: CircuitBreaker
          args:
            name: chat-service
            fallbackUri: forward:/message-fallback
        - RewritePath=/chat/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
    - id: chat-service-sockjs
      uri: http://chat-service
      predicates:
        - Path=/websocket/info/**
    - id: chat-service-websocket
      uri: lb:ws://chat-service
      predicates:
        - Path=/chat/**
```

My MessageBrokerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketMessageBrokerConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private final TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    public WebSocketMessageBrokerConfig(@Lazy TaskScheduler taskScheduler) {
        this.taskScheduler = taskScheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/conversation")
                .setHeartbeatValue(new long[]{1000, 1000})
                .setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/chat");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

My Websocket controller

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class WsConversationController 

    @MessageMapping("/startConversation/{id}")
    @SendTo("/conversation/{id}")
    public String startConversation(@DestinationVariable String id) {
        return "Hello";
    }

    @MessageMapping("/sendMessage/{id}")
    @SendTo("/conversation/{id}")
    public String sendMessage(@DestinationVariable String id) {
        return "Received";
    }

    @MessageMapping("/stopConversation/{id}")
    @SendTo("/conversation/{id}")
    public String stopConversation(@DestinationVariable String id) {
        return "Stopped";
    }
}
```

My ReactJS app

```
const ChatBoxPanel = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<ChatState>({
    stompClient: null,
    id: '',
  })

  const initWs = () => {
    const initStompClient = () => {
      const stompClient = Stomp.over(() => new SockJS('http://localhost:8088/chat/websocket')) // 8088 is gateway's port
      const id = uuidv4()

      const onConnected = () => {

        stompClient.publish({
          destination: `/chat/startConversation/${id}`,
          body: 'Start',
        })

        stompClient.subscribe('/conversation/' + id, (message) => {
          // do something when receive message
        })
      }

      const onError = (error) => {
        console.log('error', error)
      }

      stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError)

      setState({
        ...state,
        id,
        stompClient,
      })
    }

    initStompClient()
  }

  const sendMessage = (message: string) => {
    if (state.stompClient) {
      state.stompClient.publish({
        destination: `/chat/sendMessage/${state.id}`,
        body: message,
      })
    }
  }

  const closeWs = () => {
    if (state.stompClient) {
      state.stompClient.publish({
        destination: `/chat/stopConversation/${state.id}`,
      })
      state.stompClient.disconnect(() => setState({ ...state, stompClient: null }))
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    initWs()
    return closeWs()
  }, [])

  return (
    <ChatPanel
      key={'chat-panel'}
      onSend={sendMessage}
      onClose={closeWs}
    />
  )
}
```

Browser's console log on the first load
[console log when error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeclQ.png)

Browser's console log after refresh
[console log when no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL0zY.png)

Please help